# Telnet Q State Option Logic RFC1143 example code - explaination sought

Tags: c++, c, telnet

I need/want to implement a [RFC1143](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1143) compliant Telnet sub-option negotiation system in the MUD client I am coding for but I am having difficulty translating the methodology in [Section 7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1143#section-7) into workable C/C++ code.  I have, as the text suggests as one way to do it, two six state enums - I understand that given the bit patterns chosen an option is considered to be active if, and only if, for a `TelnetQStateFlag` instance `state` , `state == QStateYes`:

```
    enum TelnetQStateFlag {
                                      // +-----If set then we have a queued
                                      // |     request for the opposite state
                                      // |+----If set then we want the opposite
                                      // ||+---Must be only one set for option
                                      // |||   to be active
                      QStateNo = 0x0, // 000 - No
                  QStateWantNo = 0x2, // 010 - Want No and we/he do not want to change to Yes
                 QStateWantYes = 0x3, // 011 - Want Yes and we/he do not want to change to No
                     QStateYes = 0x1, // 001 - Yes
    QStateWantYesQueueOpposite = 0x7, // 111 - Yes but we/he wants to change to no
     QStateWantNoQueueOpposite = 0x6  // 110 - No but we/he wants to change to yes
    };

    TelnetQStateFlag[256] mMyOptions;
    TelnetQStateFlag[256] mHisOptions;
```

By default/design/magic all the options will default to the `QStateNo` but I can see that I should, on initialisation set the ones (specific values of the `size_t` variable `optionIndex`) that MY end is prepared to handle by setting `mMyOptions[optionIndex] = QStateWantYes` and similarly the ones that we are prepared to accept from HIM as `mHisOptions[optionIndex] = QStateWantYes`.

Can someone talk me through - slowly - how to handle requests from one party to negotiate to control an option at the other end - both for the cases where the other end will *and* will not accept such an option; and how this works for *both* directions possibly in an overlapping situation?

I have been through and starting from the referred to RFC I have edited it to express the transitions in six-states:

```
There are two sides, we (us) and he (him).  Originally RFC1143 kept two
sets of two variables:

us:      state of option on our side (NO/WANTNO/WANTYES/YES)  
usq:     a queue bit (EMPTY/OPPOSITE) if us is WANTNO or WANTYES  

him:     state of option on his side  
himq:    a queue bit if him is WANTNO or WANTYES  

An option is enabled if and only if its state is YES.

Note that below us/usq and him/himq has been combined into two six-choice
states:    

∙ NO              default (starting) state
∙ WANTYES         no pending request for this option to be enabled
∙ WANTYESQUEUEDNO already requested for this option to be enabled  
∙ WANTNO          no pending request for this option to be disabled  
∙ WANTNOQUEUEDYES already requested for this option to be disabled  
∙ YES             state is enabled - ONLY state in which option is ACTIVE

"ERROR" below means that producing diagnostic information may be a good idea,
though it isn't required.

Upon receipt of WILL(for his state){DO(for our state)}, we choose based upon
him{us} state:

∘ NO (if we agree)        ==> YES and send DO{WILL}
∘ NO (if we do not agree) ==> NOCHANGE but still send DONT{WONT}
∘ YES                     ==> NOCHANGE
∘ WANTNO                  ==> NO; ERROR: DONT{WONT} answered by WILL{DO}
∘ WANTNOQUEUEDYES         ==> WANTYES; ERROR: DONT{WONT} answered by WILL{DO}†
∘ WANTYES                 ==> YES
∘ WANTYESQUEUEDNO         ==> WANTNO and send DONT{WONT}

† This behaviour is debatable; DONT{WONT} will never be answered by WILL{DO}
over a reliable connection between TELNETs compliant with this RFC, so this
was chosen:
  1. not to generate further messages, because if we know we're dealing with
     a non-compliant TELNET we shouldn't trust it to be sensible;
  2. to empty the queue sensibly.

Upon receipt of WONT{DONT}, we choose based upon him{us} state:
∙ NO                      ==> NOCHANGE
∙ YES                     ==> NO and send DONT{WONT}
∙ WANTNO                  ==> NO
∙ WANTNOQUEUEDYES         ==> WANTYES and send DO{WILL}
∙ WANTYES                 ==> NO ‡
∙ WANTYESQUEUEDNO         ==> NO ※

‡ Here is the only spot a length-two queue could be useful; after a WILL{DO}
negotiation was refused, a queue of WONT{DONT} WILL{DO} would mean to request
the option again. This seems of too little utility and too much potential
waste; there is little chance that the other side will change its mind
immediately.

※ Here we don't have to generate another request because we've{he's} been
"refused into" the correct state anyway.

If we decide to ask him to enable {we want to enable ourself}:
∘ NO              ==> WANTYES and send DO{WILL}
∘ YES             ==> NOCHANGE; ERROR: already enabled
∘ WANTNO          ==> WANTNOQUEUEDYES
∘ WANTNOQUEUEDYES ==> NOCHANGE; ERROR: cannot initiate new request in the
                      middle of negotiation.
∘ WANTYES         ==> NOCHANGE; ERROR: already negotiating for enable
∘ WANTYESQUEUEDNO ==> WANTYES

If we decide to ask him to disable {we want to disable ourself}:
∙ NO              ==> NOCHANGE; ERROR: already disabled
∙ YES             ==> WANTNO and send DONT{WONT}
∙ WANTNO          ==> NOCHANGE; error: already negotiating for disable
∙ WANTNOQUEUEDYES ==> WANTNO
∙ WANTYES         ==> WANTYESQUEUEDNO
∙ WANTYESQUEUEDNO ==> NOCHANGE; error: already queued a disable request
                      and must not initiate new request in the middle of
                      negotiation

We handle the option on our side by the same procedures, with DO<->WILL,
DONT<->WONT, him<->us swapped as shown above.
```

Update 2017/07/26:
One aspect that is a little confusing to me is the case when he has an option that is enabled (in YES state) and we want him to disable it - according to this we set our record of his state to WANTNO {and send him the DONT command} - but this has moved our record of the state *away from the YES state* and the guide suggests that the option is now to be considered *disabled* even though we have not yet got a WONT to confirm it - fair enough he MUST accept it as the disabled state corresponding to the vanilla NVT requires that - but surely it does not take effect until we get the acknowledgement?

Comment: >default/design/magic   The word you are looking for is  "luck", as there are no guarantees to that effect.

Comment: In situations like this WireShark or `tcpdump` and a tried-and-true `telnet` client will provide some examples you can work from.

Comment: @Frank Well I will explicitly setup those two arrays if needed but that isn't really the core of my question - I would like a walk-through of https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1143#section-7 so as to work with the options structures (well, _arrays_) I propose.